# jquery on plugin disables second after the first one is triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a plugin`$(".multiselect").twosidedmultiselect();` that takes a select list and create a second "list" so that I can drag selected items from one to the other.
I also am using the JQuery UI component resize to allow the user to make the selectlists bigger if they want to see more selections.

```
 $(function () {
         $(".rcTestx").resizable({
            maxWidth: 250,
            minWidth: 200,
            minHeight: 75
        }); });
```

IF I resize the select lists first everything works fine but if I try to resize the select lists after I have triggered the first plugin the resizing no longer works.

Any ideas? What might be the best way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: You have to re-initialize the resizeable plugin after you add more lists. Your current code only affects elements that exist at the time that the code is ran.

Comment: Jquery rookie here.  Any suggestions on the best way to do that?Thanks

Comment: Where are you adding the new elements? And, if you are using jQuery 1.8, what version of jQuery UI are you using?